# Why does $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{H}) = \mathrm{Isom}^{+}(\mathbb{H})$?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $T \in \mathrm{Isom}^{+}(\mathbb{H})$ . With out loss of generality we may assume that $T$ fixes two points $P,P′$ on the imaginary axis $i\mathbb{R}$. Now let $Q \in \mathbb{H}$. Since $d(P,Q) = d(P,T(Q))$, the point $T (Q)$ lies on the circle radius $d(P, Q)$ centre $P$ . Likewise $T (Q)$ lies on the circle radius $d(P′,Q)$ centre $P′$. Since these two circles are also Euclidean circles, they intersect in precisely two points. (One on each side of the imaginary axis.) Clearly, one of these two points is $Q$.

Now it is told to me that since $T$ preserves orientation that intact $T$ it must be that $T(Q) = Q$. But I cannot realise this truth.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Here $\mathbb{H}$ is the hyperbolic plane with standard metric, and $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ is the group of orientation preserving conformal bijections from $\mathbb{H}$ to itself.

$\mathrm{Isom}^{+}(\mathbb{H})$ is the group of orientation preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane. Where by orientation preserving I mean that $f \in \mathrm{Isom}^{+}(\mathbb{H})$ if it is a differentiable function when viewed as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$, and the determinant of this derivative is non-zero everywhere.

Comment: So, this is to be the upper half-plane model of Hyperbolic Geometry. The fixed points of a given geodesic line lie on the real axis. To be shown: The transformations that map H into itself are the linear fractional transformations. I'm borrowing statements from Complex Analysis.

Comment: Conformal bijections that do not preserve orientation can all be produced by composition with reflection across the imaginary axis, $z \mapsto - \bar{z}$

Comment: Sorry of course I mean that $Aut(H)$ consists of all orientation preserving conformal bijections $H \mapsto H$